# Cpanel Apache mod_userdir Showing Not Supported Error on PHP File Execution

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cpanel, whm

I access the web from an IP address like http://xx.xx.xx.xx/~cpaneluser. With this I'm able to access the html file but when I try to open a .php file it's shows `Not Supported Error`. Please help me to solve this issue.

Hear I have `cPanel/WHM` Both Access and it's hosted on the `Amazon AWS EC2`.

Comment: What`s the OS you are using ?

Comment: Thanks For Quick Replay and I use "Linux version 4.9.75-25.55.amzn1.x86_64" Amazon Linux AMI

Answer (score 19):

A “Not Supported” message will show because PHP is not able to run under root using cPanel.

To allow scripts to run firstly install and enable suPHP, then set the PHP Handler to use suPHP and it should allow you to run .php scripts under temp URLs.

1. Login to cPanel WHM and install suPHP (Choose EasyApache 4 from the menu then choose "customize" - In Apache Modules, search "mod_suphp" and then click 'Next' to provision the installation.
2. Once suPHP has been installed you need to enable the PHP Handler to use it. Access “Software > MultiPHP Manager” in WHM as root. Click on PHP Handlers. Click on 'Edit' for the respective PHP version and select suPHP from the dropdown. (Usually set to CGI by default) Click on Apply.
3. Now, try accessing the php file from the temp URL and it should work.

Comment: This doesn't worked for me instead is started showing 500 Internal server error from cPanel

Comment: @AbdulRehman This error  is usually related to a permissions/ownership issue, suPHP requires that the files are owned by the user name